# Move domain name from one account to another at GoDaddy

Tags: domains

How can I move my domain name from one user account to another at GoDaddy?

I have two accounts at GoDaddy. I have the domain name in the 1st account and server in the 2nd account. I would like to move my domain name from the 1st account to the second.

Comment: If this is not an obvious feature in GoDaddy's control panel then I would contact GoDaddy support.

Comment: You should ask this questions to godaddy. I believe that you can do this via their control panel

Answer (score 2):

GoDaddy has a help document on how to "[Move a domain to another GoDaddy account](https://www.godaddy.com/help/move-a-domain-to-another-godaddy-account-822)"

---

> If you want to move a domain name from one account with us to another — it's called an Account Change.
>
> After you complete the following steps, we send the owner of the
>   receiving account an email with instructions to confirm the move. The
>   recipient must confirm the domain name move within 10 days. After that
>   time, the transaction times out and you must re initiate it.
>
> A domain name must be in active status to change accounts. If a domain
>   is in active status but past its expiration date, it will not allow
>   the account change to be initiated. Domains that change accounts will
>   have a 10-day transfer lock for fraud protection.
>
> 1. Log in to your GoDaddy account.
> 2. Next to Domains, click Manage.
> 3. Select the domain name you want to move, click Settings icon and select Domain Settings.
> 4. Under Additional Settings, click Transfer domain to another GoDaddy account.